# angular 2 include html templates

Tags: html, angular

in angular 2 I need to create a large html-template with redundant parts.
Therefore I want to create multiple html-templates and put them together by including them in the main html-file (like ng-include in angular1)

But how can I include sub-templates in the main-template?

example:

```
<!-- test.html -->

<div>
    this is my Sub-Item
    <!-- include sub1.html here-->
</div>
<div>
    this is second Sub-Item
    <!-- include sub2.html here-->
</div>
```

-

```
<!-- sub1.html -->
<div>
    <button>I'am sub1</button>
</div>
```

-

```
<!-- sub2.html -->
<div>
    <div>I'am sub2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't it have any angular context in it? or just `div` and `static text`?

Comment: sure it does. I have planty of {{}} and *ngIf, ngFor,... but how can in include other templates in the main template?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863663/complex-nesting-of-partials-and-templates

Comment: @natel your link is about angular1-routing...not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: ng-include is not in the scope of angular2. you should use CFR.

Comment: and CFR stands for?

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver`. use if it has angular context. You can also use `routing` with `name-outlet` feature.

Comment: Just use a Sub1 component and a Sub2 component. It's not clear, in your example, where the redundancy is, though. But if you want to have a reusable piece of HTML, well, that's what a component is for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create components like sub1 sub2 etc. And On those child components add these html files as template .

On main html call the component selectors respectively. It will work

Comment: thank you. I guess I will do it like that...wanted to get around creating Components for each template...but thank you :)

Comment: Okey if you face any issue ping here.

Comment: @user2638975: test.html will be

<sub1></sub1>
<sub2></sub2>

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you first of all that **`ng-include`** from **`Angular1.x`** is not supported by Angular2 so obviously **`$Compile`** is not present in **`Angular2`**. So, you can go ahead with **`CRF-ComponentFactoryResolver`** as shown here to add HTML dynamically with angular context.

**DEMO--(CFR)** : **https://plnkr.co/edit/YdRlULhWQR3L3akAr2eb?p=preview**

---

If your HTML piece has angular context, you should use **`CFR-ComponentFactoryResolver`**.

As in **`sub1.html`**, you have **`button`**, you might want to click it and fire its click event. This can be achieved with **`CFR`** as shown below,

You can do lot with **`CRF`**. This is probably the easiest example.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

     <button (click)="addComponents()">Add HTML (dynamically using CRF)</button>

     <h1>Angular2 AppComponent</h1>
     <hr>

     <div>
     <h5>sub1.html goes here</h5>
      <div class="container">
        <template #subContainer1></template>
      </div>
     </div>

     <hr>
     <h5>sub2.html goes here</h5>
     <div class="container">
        <template #subContainer2></template>
     </div>
  `,

})
export class App {
    name:string;
    @ViewChild('subContainer1', {read: ViewContainerRef}) subContainer1: ViewContainerRef;
    @ViewChild('subContainer2', {read: ViewContainerRef}) subContainer2: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(
      private compFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
      ) {
      this.name = 'Angular2'
    }

    addComponents() {

      let compFactory: ComponentFactory;

      compFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Part1Component);
      this.subContainer1.createComponent(compFactory);


      compFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Part2Component);
      this.subContainer2.createComponent(compFactory);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` is no longer in the core API.

Comment: Using builtin classes in an example, without showing the corresponding import line, is really crappy