# Angular2 split template file?

Tags: angular, templates, angularjs-ng-include

In Angular 1.5 I used to split up large template files by using ng-include. For example I had a template called layout.html that contained a sidebar, the header and the navigation, I included all of those three elements with ng-include. Gave me more overview than one large HTML template file.

Is there any way to solve this in Angular 2?

Comment: just create a component with a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 does not support ng-include.  Here's a similar question with more answers: [angular 2 include html templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316341/angular-2-include-html-templates)

But TL;DR: in Angular 2 the basic unit is a component, not a template.

More in-depth discussion on GitHub here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7596